# How to update preview of NSPrintPanel?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I added a custom view controller to the NSPrintPanel with `.addAccessoryController` - this works fine.
I can change properties and I see that they affect the printview, but only if I refresh the view by changing the paper format or layout.

there must be a way to tell the `NSPrintPanel` to refresh the print view, I tried .needsDisplay = true without luck

In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsprintpanelaccessorizing/1490516-keypathsforvaluesaffectingprevie) is a mention of implementing `keyPathsForValuesAffectingPreview`, but I was not able to figure out that to return there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keyPathsForValuesAffectingPreview` is implemented the same way as any other `keyPathsForValuesAffecting<Foo>` method specifying KVO dependencies, with the exception that it is declared on an instance instead of on a type. For more information on declaring KVO dependencies, see this page in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html

Basically, in a nutshell, you want to return a set of key paths to properties that, when they are changed, should cause the preview to change. In Swift, there are a few extra caveats not present in Objective-C:

1. All of the properties in question must be marked with the `@objc` attribute.
2. All of the properties in question must be KVO-compliant, which essentially means that:

   - For a stored property, add the `dynamic` keyword on the property declaration.
   - For a computed property `foo`, add a static `keyPathsForValuesAffectingFoo` property listing its dependencies as a `Set` of `String`s.

As an example, suppose I have a property `foo` which is a String. I also have a property `bar` whose value is derived from the value of `foo`. If `bar` changes, I want the preview to change. I would write my code like this:

```
@objc dynamic var foo: String = "Foo"

@objc static let keyPathsForValuesAffectingBar: Set<String> = [#keyPath(foo)]
@objc var bar: String { return self.foo }

func keyPathsForValuesAffectingPreview() -> Set<String> { return [#keyPath(bar)] }
```

If the `foo` property is changed in the scenario above, the KVO notifications for the `foo` key path will be sent, since `foo` is dynamic. Next, KVO notifications for the `bar` key path will be sent, since `bar` is dependent on the `foo` key path. This, in turn, will cause your preview to be updated, since NSPrintPanel will be watching the `bar` key path that we returned from `keyPathsForValuesAffectingPreview`.